# Number of undirected forests with exactly 2 trees on $n$ vertices - Solution verification

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> What is the number of undirected forests with exactly 2 trees on $n$ vertices?

The "obvious" solution I found is by summing for number of vertices in each tree and dividing by 2 because we created order between the 2 trees: $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{k=n-1} \binom{n}{k} k^{k-2} (n-k)^{n-k-2}$

Another solution I thought about is first looking at all possible trees on $n$ vertices, and then removing one edge, which would leave us with 2 trees: $n^{n-2}(n-1)$. We would get each possible combination of 2 trees this way because they make a tree when connected, so this is given by Cayley's theorem. I'm not sure how to prove we would get no duplicates though.

Would appreciate feedback about both solutions.

Comment: With the second approach you definitely get a lot of duplicates: you can add an edge to a pair of trees in multiple ways to make it a spanning tree.

Comment: @DánielG. Could you provide an example please?

Comment: On three (labelled) vertices there are $3$ suitable forests (each being an edge and an isolated vertex). Your second formula instead gives $6$ as the solution. That's because each edge + isolated vertex can be obtained in two different ways by leaving an edge from a spanning tree (i.e. a path of length two).

Comment: @DánielG. Thanks. If anyone sees a simple fix to the 2nd solution I'll be glad to hear

Comment: According to https://oeis.org/A083483, the answer is $n^{n-4}(n-1)(n+6)/2$, but no proof is provided. Based on that formula, it seems a combinatorial proof would be really tricky.